# Failure to resolve: org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre8:1.2.71 error for a Multi-module Kotlin project

Tags: android, gradle, kotlin

I'm using Android Studio version 3.2 and I have a multi-module Gradle build.

I have a file called `dependencies.gradle` that looks like this:

```
   ext{
  //Android
  androidBuildToolsVersion = "26.0.0"
  androidMinSdkVersion = 21
  androidTargetSdkVersion = 26
  androidCompileSdkVersion = 26
  kotlinVersion = '1.2.71'

  //Libraries
  supportLibraryVersion = '26.1.0'
  rxJavaVersion = '2.2.0'
  javaxAnnotationVersion = '1.0'
  javaxInjectVersion = '1'
  rxKotlinVersion = '2.2.0'
  androidAnnotationsVersion='21.0.3'
  daggerVersion = '2.14.1'


  //Testing
  jUnitVersion = '4.12'
  assertJVersion = '3.11.0'
  mockitoKotlinVersion ='2.0.0-RC2'
  robolectricVersion = '3.4.2'

  domainDependencies = [
      javaxAnnotation: "javax.annotation:jsr250-api:${javaxAnnotationVersion}",
      javaxInject: "javax.inject:javax.inject:${javaxInjectVersion}",
      rxJava: "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxkotlin:${rxJavaVersion}"
  ]

  domainTestDependencies = [
      junit: "junit:junit:${jUnitVersion}",
      mockito: "com.nhaarman.mockitokotlin2:mockito-kotlin:${mockitoKotlinVersion}",
      assertj: "org.assertj:assertj-core:${assertJVersion}"
  ]

  dataDependencies = [
      rxKotlin: "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxkotlin:${rxKotlinVersion}",
      javaxAnnotation: "javax.annotation:jsr250-api:${javaxAnnotationVersion}",
       kotlin:    "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre8:${kotlinVersion}",
      javaxInject: "javax.inject:javax.inject:${javaxInjectVersion}",
  ]

  dataTestDependencies = [
      junit: "junit:junit:${jUnitVersion}",
      kotlinJUnit: "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test-junit:${kotlinVersion}",
      mockito: "com.nhaarman.mockitokotlin2:mockito-kotlin:${mockitoKotlinVersion}",
      assertj: "org.assertj:assertj-core:${assertJVersion}",
      robolectric: "org.robolectic:robolectric:${robolectricVersion}"
  ]

}
```

I want to write tests for the Data Module in my app and my `build.gradle` for the Data module is as follows.

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin'

dependencies {
    compile project(':Domain')

    def dataDependencies = rootProject.ext.dataDependencies
    def dataTestDependencies = rootProject.ext.dataTestDependencies



    implementation dataDependencies.javaxAnnotation
    implementation dataDependencies.javaxInject
    implementation dataDependencies.rxKotlin
    implementation dataDependencies.kotlin

    testImplementation dataTestDependencies.junit
    testImplementation dataTestDependencies.mockito
    testImplementation dataTestDependencies.assertj
    testImplementation dataTestDependencies.kotlinJUnit


}

sourceCompatibility = "1.8"
targetCompatibility = "1.8"
```

But when I sync my Gradle file I get the following errors from Android Studio.

- `Failed to resolve: org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre8:1.2.71`
- `Failed to resolve: org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test-junit:1.2.71`

Would really appreciate some help on this, as I'm sure I have the right package names. Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you find a solution?  I am facing the same issue.

Comment: Yes I did. @Igor Ganapolsky, make sure that your internet connection has no proxy settings/firewalls that are blocking you from being able to download the dependency. It seemed that my problem was that my internet connection was configured improperly hence the bug.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to the build.gradle in the app folder 
implementation group: 'org.jetbrains.kotlin', name: 'kotlin-stdlib', version: '1.2.0'
This solve my problem..

in your case change the version: implementation group: 'org.jetbrains.kotlin', name: 'kotlin-stdlib', version: '1.2.71'

Comment: changing the Version name to 1.2.0 solves the first error but I still have a problem with the second and should I be regressing to an older version of Kotlin to fix this bug?